# 404 error when deploying spring mvc on jboss 7

Tags: spring-mvc, jboss-eap-7

I am deploying spring mvc project on jboss eap 1.7 open source. Using Java 1.8 version. Post deployment when I hit my application on browser I could see and error as 404 url not found. What needs to be done to resolve this issue.

Comment: Check your web.xml / servlet configurations

Comment: "hit your application": from (jboss) "management page" ... or typed address manually in browser? ...from my experience 404 never "fails"

Comment: I have hit the application on browser manually.

Comment: Servlet configuration is fine. I am able to run this application on tomcat. But while running on jboss it is giving this error

Comment: you hit "the wrong address" (context path ... or typo ..or maybe even port)

Comment: ...try from "jboss management"!

Comment: Could you please let me know, how could we hit the application from jboss management.